# Magento2 : How to get when page content load

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I want to add some custom script on checkout page content, but my script is executing before content load.

```
require([
        'jquery',
    ], function ($) {
        $(window).load(function(){
            // my script here
        });
    });
```

How to add script which run just after all page content load.

Comment: use window.load in your function

Comment: @AasimGoriya, I tried `window.load` but still page content loading after my script execution.

Answer (score 6):

**For knockout render complete call js use below function**

You can use default ko function **afterRender** to load your code after ko content completed,

```
<input type="text"
        class="input-text" data-bind="afterRender:onRenderComplete"
        name="inputname" />
```

*In knockout file,*

```
onRenderComplete: function () {
    // call your script code
},
```

**For Normal page after page ready use domReady!**

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
        // my script here        
});
```

Comment: I don't want to edit checkout page template to add `onRenderComplete`.

Comment: domReady doesn't help to wait for all content loaded for instance in checkout page...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am late but try with `domReady`:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
   // your script here
});
```

Comment: As per @Gediminas this dosent work on checkout page.